# Rendering docx files as django templates: Word breaks {{}}-blocks

Tags: django, file-io, django-templates, openxml

I'm writing an django application which renders docx document based on user input. The main idea is: "docx is django template". So, I need to unzip word file, extract XML with markup, render it as django template and put everything back.

Everything works just fine, except annoying problem with creating initial document (I use standard editors such as MS Word itself and LibreOffice Writer): while setting up markdown, editor can break template blocks (`{{}}` and `{%%}`) with XML tags.

For example: `<w:t>{{doc_title}}</w:t>` can become

```
<w:t>{{</w:t><w:t>doc_title</w:t>}}
```

Is that any way I could avoid this, except inserting template blocks directly in XML?